# how to make drag and drop jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've been wondering how to make drag and drop with jQuery, because it is difficult to use the javascript drag and drop, and I prefer to use jQuery instead of javascript. What I want is for the child div to be draggable, and only be droppable in the parent divs. When the child div is dropped, if it is not in a parent div, then it will revert back to the last parent div it was in. if the child div was dropped in a parent div, then it will go to the top left corner of the parent div it was dropped in.  The child div is only draggable.
I am fine with using jQuery UI, but I couldn't get the .droppable() function to work.

## **HTML:**

```
<div id="div1" class="div">
<div id="image" class="image"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="div">
</div>
```

## **CSS:**

```
.div {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 5px;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 3px solid black
        }
.image {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: khaki;
    }
```

## **jQuery (only drag):**

```
    $("document").ready(function() {
    $(".image").draggable();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9pvbuue/8/ 
I would highly appreciate if you could directly give me a code for the answer, instead of indirect answers that tell me nothing of how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery has no `draggable` API.

You can use [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [jQuery UI droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) OR use `HTML5` [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

**Update**

According to updated description of the original question, demo solution code:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".child").draggable({
    revert: true
  });

  $(".parent").droppable({
    accept: '.child',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 .parent {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5px;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border: 3px solid black
 }
 .child {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-color: khaki;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
</div>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: What I want to do is have a helper, which is a clone of the original div, be able to be moved into the other div, or div2, and adjusts in the div2 to a specific position in div2, and returned if not dropped in a certain area of div2. Same applies for div1.

Comment: @RandomChannel Do you mean working like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kding007/g2efds1z/1/

Comment: No, that is the same exact thing that I put. What I am asking for is to find a way to drag the div with the class of "image" into the div with an id of "div2" with the div with the class of "images" moving to a specific place in the div with the id of "div2", and the draggable div is returned to the div it was in last, if not put inside of another div.

Comment: Like he said, use the JQuery UI library and you can accomplish this.

Comment: You could use the .droppable() method, and make the div with the class of "image" only able to be dropped in a certain radius of the parent div, and the child div moves to a specific location in the parent div. I can't get this method to work, though.

Comment: @Ageonix I am a beginner at jQuery, I am already using the jQuery UI library, I just don't know how to use the UI library to meet my goals.

Comment: I would update your question with specifics on what you're looking for.  It's not real clear at the moment.

Comment: @RandomChannel, check this result: https://jsfiddle.net/kding007/g2efds1z/7/, does this version work as your goal?

Comment: @AndyDing Yes it was. If you make that an answer, I will make it a correct answer. Then you will get reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript.

my code is through javascript:

```
var CloneElement=document.getElementByID("ElementID").clone(true);
document.getElementByID("TargetSectionID").appendChild(CloneElement);
```

Comment: He specifically says he wants to use JQuery, not javascript.